# Understanding flink jobmanager memory

Tags: java, memory-management, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink job that has a nfs filesystem folder as a source and kafka as a sink. there are no transformations done at this point.

I have used continuousmonitoringfunction to continuously monitor for events on the folder and 
   ContinuousFileReaderOperator for reading the data.

```
ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction<String> monitoringFunction = new ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction<>(
                inputFormat, FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, env.getParallelism(),
                MONITORING_INTERVAL);

ContinuousFileReaderOperator<String> reader = new ContinuousFileReaderOperator<>(inputFormat);
```

Initial size of the folder is ~40GB with 3785468 files(in all sub directories) in it.

I have created 1 job manager with heap 25G and 2 task managers with  4 task slots and following memory values.

```
taskmanager.memory.process.size: "26g"
taskmanager.memory.flink.size: "24g"
jobmanager.heap.size: "25g"
taskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.max: "2g"
taskmanager.memory.task.off-heap.size: "1024M"
taskmanager.memory.task.heap.size: "16g"
taskmanager.memory.managed.fraction: 0.2
taskmanager.memory.network.max: "2g"
```

When the job started job manager is working on prepping the job and the prepping state is taking long time around 2 hrs. Once job starts it is working fine in transferring the files to kafka.

I am trying to fine tune the job, can anyone please help me understand what happens during prepping stage and what part of memory is important during this state ?

I am trying to play with memory params but nothing seems to work, without knowledge of what memory is used for what I am unable to proceed.

I have gone through flink documentation on memory but it is not clear on what managed memory is used for and DirectMemory is used for while processing the job.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#memory-configuration

Could some one help me understand what I should consider to fine tune the job ?

Comment: The job manager has relatively modest memory requirements, and for such a simple job, the task managers shouldn't need much memory either. Why have you sized things so large?

Comment: I have tried with low memory and job was failing with following error, thought it is memory related and increased the memory. now job is working but with delayed performance. That is why I am trying to understand how I can tune 
WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@172.16.97.247:45903] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@172.16.97.247:45903]] Caused by: [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /172.16.97.247:45903]

Comment: You can configure your cluster to use grafana/prometheus to export the job metrics, configure the dashboard to monitor your application to see the memory consumption, cpu load etc etc. Your setup uses a lot of memory for what is supposed to do, looking into the metrics you can have a much better vision

Comment: The problem should not be related to the available memory configuration of the JobManager. It looks like an unstable network connection. Please also take a look at the logs of the TaskManagers. They might help you understand what's going wrong.

Comment: I experience OOM on TM with ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction as well, on a folder with many files. The first phase is a non-parallel task, doing `getInputSplitsSortedByModTime`. This step is *very* memory intensive when there are a lot of files. Interested in insights on this... cc @DavidAnderson